# jQuery AJAX post submission to a PHP script multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, submission

I am trying to do a form submission without having the page reload.  It works the first time, but when I try and do a second submission the page is refreshed.

I would like to be able to do several submissions with the new data propagating into the current  element.  What am I missing.

Here is my first page form.php

```
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
  <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#form").validate({
            debug: false,
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                jQuery.post('formPost.php',
                    jQuery("#form").serialize(), function (data) {
                    jQuery('#Box').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    // ]]>
</script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Box">
      <form id="form" name="form" method="POST" action="">
        <select name="color">
          <option>red</option>
          <option>white</option>
          <option>blue</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /><br />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my second page formPost.php

```
<?php

  switch ($_POST['color'])
  {
    case 'red':
      echo 'you chose red<br /><br />';
      break;

    case 'blue':
      echo 'you chose blue<br /><br />';
      break;

    case 'white':
      echo 'you chose white<br /><br />';
      break;
  }
?>
<form id="form" name="form" method="POST" action="">
  <select name="color">
    <option>red</option>
    <option>white</option>
    <option>blue</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /><br />
</form>
```

I want to be able to reuse the same form for multiple form submissions while staying on the same page and having the data apprear in the same div without refreshing the page.  Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
  <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        initializeForm();
    });

    function initializeForm() {
        jQuery("#form").validate({
            debug: false,
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                jQuery.post('formPost.php',
                    jQuery("#form").serialize(), function (data) {
                    jQuery('#Box').html(data);
                    initializeForm();
                });
            }

        });
    }

    // ]]>
</script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Box">
      <form id="form" name="form" method="POST" action="">
        <select name="color">
          <option>red</option>
          <option>white</option>
          <option>blue</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /><br />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tested this out and it works locally for me.  I hope this helps!

Comment: But the form will change with each answer.  So in my live version, if you choose red, then the formPost.php page will show a new form and this will continue for about 10 form questions.  any ideas?

Comment: Ok..sorry I did not realize the importance of the new form.  I separated out part of your JavaScript function to make it reuseable because you need to re-initialize the AJAX form after the new form is incorporated into the HTML.

Comment: Ok, so is it possible to do the jQuery post and have the new info continue to propagate in the main div?  On my formPost.php page I will have the form change based on the choices from the previous form.

Comment: Oh yeah... Ok you nailed it!  That works perfect.  I hadn't tried it before I made the previous comment.  Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 0):

You validate action is being bound to the form that exists when the document is ready (since it's in document.ready). However, your PHP script is replacing that form with a different form, so the form that validate is bound to no longer exists. When you you're binding events, you can use something like a [live binding](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to get around this. You probably can't use that with the validate plugin, though. What you should really be doing is writing your response to a different element.

So, something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery.noConflict ();
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#form").validate({
        debug: false,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        jQuery.post('formPost.php', 
                     jQuery("#form").serialize(), 
                     function(data) {
                       jQuery('#result').html(data); // Note that this modifies #result instead of #Box.
                     });
        }
      });
    });
    // ]]>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Box">
    <form id="form" name="form" method="POST" action="">
      <select name="color">
        <option>red</option>
        <option>white</option>
        <option>blue</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /><br />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="result" /> <!-- Here is where we put out result. -->
</body>
</html>
```

and then just

```
<?php

  switch ($_POST['color'])
  {
    case 'red':
      echo 'you chose red<br /><br />';
      break;

    case 'blue':
      echo 'you chose blue<br /><br />';
      break;

    case 'white':
      echo 'you chose white<br /><br />';
      break;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Except I need the result to propagate the next form.  I want to go through about 10 questions and with each answer the formPost.php will return a comment and new form.  any ideas?